# CakePHP 3.8 issue when loading SecurityComponent

Tags: ajax, security, cakephp, cakephp-3.x

**Exact Problem and the Solution**

Upon activating the CakePHP (3) Security Component, when loading a form, you generate three hidden fields in the form. These are '_Token[fields]', '_Token[unlocked]' and '_Token[debug]'. What exactly happens is the Form->end() method calls the secure() method (see FormHelper) when the request data contains a ['Token'] parameter.

The forms that were not working for me were all forms rendered as an Element. For these forms, the '$this->request->params' did not contain the parameter normally generated by the Security Component.

Solution was in manually adding the parameter to the request data..

```
$this->request->params['_Token'] = ['unlockedFields' => []];
```

This than runs through the secure() method of FormHelper, as it should, and token parameters are correctly added.

**Original Question**

I have an issue using the SecurityComponent of CakePHP 3.8.

Everything was working fine, until I loaded Component in my AppController.

```
$this->loadComponent('Security');
```

Upon clicking a button I make an ajax call.

```
var csrf_token = <?php echo json_encode($this->request->getParam('_csrfToken')) ?>; 
var checkouturl = "<?php echo $this->Url->build('/orders/checkout', true) ?>";  
var test = "test";


$("#checkout").click(function() {

    $.ajax({
                type: 'post',
                url: checkouturl,
                headers: {'X-CSRF-Token': csrf_token},
                data: {data : test},
                success: function(result){

                   console.log(result);

                },
                error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {

                    console.log(xhr);
                    console.log(thrownError);

                }
        });              
    });
```

This call was working fine, now I get the following error message (400 bad request). Apparently using the Security Component checks for an additional token apart from the csrf-token.

```
'_Token' was not found in request data.
```

Can anyone explain what I can do about this? I only find information related to forms, but this is an ajax call. I would like to keep the Security Component enabled.

Example of a non-working form..

```
echo $this->Form->create($athlete, ['url' => ['controller' => 'Athletesux', 'action' => $action]]);

echo $this->Form->control('user_id', ['type' => 'hidden', 'value' => $userid]);
echo $this->Form->control('first_name');
echo $this->Form->control('last_name');
echo $this->Form->control('threek_time', ['value' => $athlete['3K_time']]); 
echo $this->Form->control('fivek_time', ['value' => $athlete['5K_time']]);     
echo $this->Form->control('tenk_time', ['value' => $athlete['10K_time']]); 
echo $this->Form->select('country', $countryoptions);  
echo $this->Form->select('gender', $gender);   
echo $this->Form->button('Add Athlete');
echo $this->Form->end();
```

Thanks!

HTML Generated..

[image]

Comment: My first question would be, why do you want to protect your AJAX requests with the security component? If that is your goal at all...

Comment: I want to use the security component to lift the security level of my application in general. I am a bit surprised to see that just activating this component causes problems with my ajax calls.

Comment: I found a way to conditionally load the component so it does not refer to ajax calls. Now I get the same error for normal form sends.. Strange that there is not more documentation on this issue.

Comment: I found this, but can't find a single example on how to exactly implement it.. Cake\View\Helper\FormHelper::end($secureAttributes = [])
$secureAttributes - Optional. Allows you to provide secure attributes which will be passed as HTML attributes into the hidden input elements generated for the SecurityComponent.

Comment: Most forms created with the form helper should work with the security component out of the box, as that is what the component is ment to be used with. What do your forms look like?

Comment: It does not work on any form.. I checked the FormHelper end()-method documentation, and apparently you need to include $secureAttributes to generate the right hidden inputs that match with the Security Component. But they do not say how to.. :-) https://book.cakephp.org/3/en/views/helpers/form.html (Closing the Form)

Comment: You do not need to, that's just an optional way to add attributes to the generated HTML elements, it has nothing to do with the actual securing process. Again, please provide an example of one of your non-working forms!

Comment: Added to original question..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211094/discussion-between-niels-vanwingh-and-ndm).

Comment: The code looks fine. What HTML is being generated for that?

Comment: Added to the original question..

Comment: Seeing that there is no `_Token` field at all, that would indicate that either the security component did not generate a `_Token` parameter on the request object (see `\Cake\Controller\Component\SecurityComponent::generateToken()`, the form helper will only generate the token field if that parameter is present), or the security component did not run, or the parameter is being removed somewhere before the form helper runs. I'd suggest that you debug these three possible points of failure first.

Comment: Can you please give me an example of how to use the method generateToken()?

Comment: Usually there should be no need to use it on your own, the security component should do it automatically. But if you were to use it manually (you should really only do that if you _definitely_ know that you _need_ to do that, or for testing purposes), then it would be as simple as for example `$this->request = $this->Security->generateToken($this->request);` (in a controller).

Comment: From the error messages I have gotten, I derive that I need three _Token parameters.. _Token[fields], _Token[unlocked], _Token[debug]. Upon debugging $this->Security->generateToken($this->request) I get this as output '_Token' => ['unlockedFields' => []'. So nothing is generated.. 
  ],

Comment: That's the expected output, the component just generates basic token information and configuration, the form helper will then use that information when generating the actual token data.

Comment: I just checked a few more forms, and apparently it does work on normal forms. The forms I tested are all generated on Elements.. These are blocking..

Comment: I know you should not use Security Component on ajax calls. But is this also true for forms generated through ajax call?

Comment: And if not, doesn't it create a security risk?

Comment: Neither elements nor AJAX requests should be a problem for generating forms with security tokens. As long as a token parameter is present on the request object, the form helper should generate the hidden token inputs. Check what happens in the source of `FormHelper::end()` and `FormHelper::secure()` for your forms in elements and on AJAX requests.

Comment: I found the solution! Thank you for your help, added it to original question..